# Android SDK error

Tags: java, android, sdk, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

After running android.bat both with and without administrator powers I get the following error:  [image: Error in command prompt]

Environment Values set as:

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin set for JAVA_HOME, JDK_HOME, and JAVA_PATH

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32; set for PATH

C:\Users\elija_000\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\lib\x86_64\swt.jar set for ANDROID_SWT

Comment: have u check java is installed or not error is not visible dear

Comment: Can you provide a microscope with that image as well?

Comment: Sorry, opening the image in a new tab should help. Java is installed, 1.7.0_71 to be exact.

Comment: I just tried it,  works just fine even without 'administrator powers'

Comment: It should, I just noted that some people were saying that running as an administrator fixed their problems, so I wanted to clarify that it didn't for me.

Comment: You have redundant environmental variables !! only PATH and JAVA_HOME are required.. JDK_HOME, JAVA_PATH are not required.. further more if you have eclipse and ADT, open eclipse go to  'window' then select 'android sdk manager'.. see if that opens or not

Comment: The redundant variables we're the problem! Thanks, I've been trying to fix this for days.

Comment: Yes, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have redundant environmental variables !! only **PATH** and **JAVA_HOME** are required.. *JDK_HOME*, *JAVA_PATH* are not required.. further more if you have eclipse and ADT, open eclipse go to 'window' then select 'android sdk manager'.. see if that opens or not to test.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall the java
maybe it will work

Comment: I just uninstalled jdk 8 for 7, so that is not the problem.

Comment: you have to see if your compiler is using 32bit or 64bit.

Comment: Deleting the redundant variables resolved the issue.

Comment: the last time I have this issue. I was using a 64bit and was prompt an error then I un-install and re-install also the same result so I install the 32bit in as well and it just work. I cant really explain where went wrong but you could give it a shot